# Drupal FEED IMPORTER - Convert XML date time to Unix timestamp using Xpath function

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, unix-timestamp, drupal-feeds

Here is my xml format. I have taken few values

Image from Content: substring-before(substring-after(content, "src="),' alt=')

How can i convert XML date and time to Unix time stamp format.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<users>
  <user>
 <id>uuid:59b3ba1f-8e9d-48f5-a73c-f404b3a8a697;id=3831</id>
 <content type="html">
<![CDATA[<img src=http://img2.tvtome.com/i/u/0aa3afb3cbe3468fc6e43e50070b0810.png alt= /><p>"With a Little Help From My Friends" is a song written by the Beatles (and expertly covered by Joe Cocker) and it could easily be the subtitle for the thirty minute comedy,</p>]]>
</content>
    <firstname>Sheila</firstname>    
    <address>2 Good St</address>
 <published>2015-04-02T09:11:44-05:00</published>        
    <contact>
      <phone>12341234</phone>
      <url>http://example.com</url>
      <email>pamela@example.com</email>
    </contact>
  </user>
<users>
```

Comment: So your issue here, how to convert dateTime string to timeStamp or how to extract the dateTime string from xml then converted to timestamp ??

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding a TAMPER PLUGIN for the particular field